# SharePoint change author

Tags: sharepoint-server, api

**Is it possible to change the Author of a discussion list using the API in SharePoint 2016?**

I am trying to update a discussion list author with the user ID19. This is what the curl request would look like:

> curl -v --ntlm -u user1:password -X  POST -d 
>   '{"CreatedByID":"19","ModifiedByID":"19"}'  -H "Content-Type:
>   application/json" -H "X-HTTP-Method: MERGE" -H "If-Match: *"
>   "https://sharepoint.mysite.com/sites/communities
>   /_vti_bin/listdata.svc/DiscussionsList(38)"

This does not return any errors, but it also doesn’t update the list item with the new author. (From what I’ve read, Author=CreatedByID). I know this is a read-only by default but I am hoping there is some way to get past this.